# Rename an image file when uploading in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

i stumbled across this function on the internet.

```
private createFileName() {
      var d = new Date(),
      n = d.getTime(),
      newFileName =  n + ".jpg";
      return newFileName;
    }
```

It's purpose is to rename an image file. The questions i have are

1. Does this restrict image upload to `jpg` only or does it convert it to
   `jpg`.
2. If it's the former how can i get the image extension before upload
   and modify `private createFileName(ext)` function like so, so as to upload
   every image type.

If it would help here is the full code

```
lastImage: string = null;
  loading: Loading;

public takePicture(sourceType) {
  // Create options for the Camera Dialog
  var options = {
    quality: 100,
    sourceType: sourceType,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
    correctOrientation: true
  };

  // Get the data of an image
  this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) => {
    // Special handling for Android library
    if (this.platform.is('android') && sourceType === this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY) {
      this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath)
        .then(filePath => {
          let correctPath = filePath.substr(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          let currentName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, imagePath.lastIndexOf('?'));
          this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
        });
    } else {
      var currentName = imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      var correctPath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
    }
  }, (err) => {
    this.presentToast('Error while selecting image.');
  });
}

   private copyFileToLocalDir(namePath, currentName, newFileName) {
  this.file.copyFile(namePath, currentName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName).then(success => {
    this.lastImage = newFileName;
  }, error => {
    this.presentToast('Error while storing file.');
  });
}


private presentToast(text) {
  let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: text,
    duration: 3000,
    position: 'top'
  });
  toast.present();
}

// Always get the accurate path to your apps folder
public pathForImage(img) {
  if (img === null) {
    return '';
  } else {
    return cordova.file.dataDirectory + img;
  }
}

public uploadImage() {
  // Destination URL
  var url = "http://my_url/uploads.php";

  // File for Upload
  var targetPath = this.pathForImage(this.lastImage);

  // File name only
  var filename = this.lastImage;

  var options = {
    fileKey: "file",
    fileName: filename,
    chunkedMode: false,
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    params : {'fileName': filename}
  };

  const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

  this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: 'Uploading...',
  });
  this.loading.present();

  // Use the FileTransfer to upload the image
  fileTransfer.upload(targetPath, url, options).then(data => {
    this.loading.dismissAll()
    this.presentToast('Image succesfully uploaded.');
  }, err => {
    this.loading.dismissAll()
    this.presentToast('Error while uploading file.');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1- It does not restrict to "jpg", and it does not convert to "jpg", as the method name says: create Filename, it creates a string, with the filename, just that.
2- The image extension will be jpg, as it is the default camera encodingType, and it seems like you are taking pictures using the camera. You can change the encodingtype in the camera options.
You can find all the camera options in https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/